# Communication between two different Stream in SCDF

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-dataflow

I am not sure whether it is possible or not.
I have a scenario where i have one SCDF Stream containing **source | processor |sink**. which is working perfectly fine. Now i need to create another Stream which will contain the same structure like "**source | processor | sink**". As per the business requirement i need to perform a task where both the stream will communicate with each other.

**E.g.** My Stream-1 sink will pass one list to Stream-2 source . and then it will manipulate that list.

**Why Second Steam :** Requirement is to create a second stream like a utility using which any other stream can also access it and get the desired output.

Let me know the way if it is possible or not.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I were to rephrase the requirement, it appears you'd want to share the data from the primary pipeline to another stream.

A stream is an unbounded data processing pipeline. Use of [TAPs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.2.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-stream-dsl-tap) in SCDF could potentially address this requirement of sharing a copy of the in-flight data from stream-1 with stream-2.

Depending on the position (*either at the `source` or `processor`*), you can TAP from the named-destination (topic/queue) and get the copy of same data to the secondary pipeline for any downstream processing.